# Cannot resolve symbol 'PhotoCaptureExample'

Tags: java, android

I am following instructions [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160123214822/http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/) to implement a photo capture in my app.

The error I am getting is on the last step, where `PhotoCaptureExample` is becoming red and saying: `Cannot resolve symbol PhotoCaptureExample`. Here is my MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected Button _button;
    protected ImageView _image;
    protected TextView _field;
    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.image );
        _field = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.field );
        _button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button );
        _button.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler() );

        _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/make_machine_example.jpg";
    }

    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick( View view ){
            startCameraActivity();
        }
    }

    protected void startCameraActivity()
    {
        File file = new File( _path );
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

        startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
    }

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "resultCode: " + resultCode );
    switch( resultCode )
    {
        case 0:
            Log.i( "MakeMachine", "User cancelled" );
            break;

        case -1:
            onPhotoTaken();
            break;
    }
}

protected void onPhotoTaken()
    {
        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );
        _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        _field.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {
        outState.putBoolean( PhotoCaptureExample.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken );
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState( Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onRestoreInstanceState()");
        if( savedInstanceState.getBoolean( PhotoCaptureExample.PHOTO_TAKEN ) ) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        }
    }
```

If you want any other information, please ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Cannot resolve symbol PhotoCaptureExample` means that the IDE can't found the class in your project or in the libraries, looking at the link you provided in the blog post there is a link to download the source code and inside the zip in '/photo_capture/src/makemachine/android/examples/' there is the class `PhotoCaptureExample` you need, you just need to import it to your project.

Comment: do i add it in the libs folder?

Comment: Nope, just copy the PhotoCaputreExample.java to where your other .java files are

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Based on Error, PhotoCaptureExample is not available.

There can be two reasons:
Either you car referring class from a jar and forgot to include it or you have defined class in different package and set its scope to protected (most probably you did this). In second case, you have to change scope of your class.